# How do I generate a list of random integers without consecutive numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

After I sort a randomly generated list, I have consecutive numbers, e.g.

```
[7, 9, 13, 47, 64, 76, 83, 94, 95, 114, 115, 116, 120, 121, 123, 124, 127, 136, 152, 154, 167, 184, 189, 205, 212, 222, 226, 229, 231, 238]
```

Here consecutive numbers are `(94, 95)`, `(120, 121)` and `(123, 124)`.
How do I remove them?

My code is:

```
while len(set(l)) != 30:
    a = random.randint(1, 240)
    l.append(a)

l = list(set(l))
l = sorted(l)

f.write(str(l))
```

I do not want to use `randrange` or `choice` from `random` module.

Comment: I would upvote, but limit reached - maybe tomorrow

Comment: What you mean by *random* is understandable, but it doesn't correspond to what `random.randint()` means by *random*. A truly random number function would supply a number that *in no way depends* on any of the previous values: it *cannot look back* at the numbers already supplied to see if there are consecutive numbers. In computing we generally have to make do with pseudorandom numbers, but the same principle applies. On the 30th call, the probability is very high that a number chosen at random will lie close to one of the previous 29. Your code already eliminates duplicates for that reason.

Answer (score 3):

Create a random number `a` and check if `a` and `a±1` are not in the set:

```
import random 
l = set()
while len(l) != 30:
    a = random.randint(1, 240)
    if not {a-1,a,a+1} & l: # set intersection: empty == False == no common numbers
        l.add(a)

l = sorted(l) # sorted creates a sorted list from any iterable

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[5, 12, 40, 47, 55, 59, 62, 73, 76, 82, 84, 89, 93, 95, 109, 
 125, 127, 141, 165, 168, 184, 187, 196, 202, 204, 210, 215, 
 218, 229, 231]
```

Directly using a set makes the check if the number (±1) is already part of your random numbers very fast.

Doku:

- [set.intersection (or &)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)

---

And as function:

```
import random

def get_random_numbers_no_neighboring_elems(min_num, max_num, amount):
    """Generates amount random numbers in [min_num,..,max_num] that do not
    include neighboring numbers."""

    # this is far from exact - it is best to have about 5+ times the amount 
    # of numbers to choose from - if the margin is too small you might take
    # very long to get all your "fitting numbers" as only about 1/4 of the range
    # is a viable candidate (worst case): 
    #   [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]: draw 2 then 5 then 8 and no more are possible 
    if (max_num-min_num) // 5 < amount:
        raise ValueError(f"Range too small - increase given range.")

    l = set()
    while len(l) != amount:  
        a = random.randint(min_num, max_num)
        if not {a-1,a,a+1} & l: # set intersection: empty == False == no commons
            l.add(a)
    return sorted(l)

print(get_random_numbers_no_neighboring_elems(1,240,80))
```

Comment: I suspect that this introduces a bias. If you tweak your algorithm to make 240 and 30 parameters rather than hard-wired, you should be able to apply it to pick 2 number sets in the range 1-5 without consecutive entries. There are 6 2-element subsets which satisfy the constraint, ideally to be chosen with probability 1/6.  But, for example, it is easy to work out that your algorithm oversamples {2,4} (picking that 1/5 of the time) and undersamples {1,5} (picking that only 2/15 times). Still, OP didn't specify anything about the distribution, so +1 for a reasonable approach.

Comment: @JohnColeman Reducing a random sampling with constraints seems a bad idea I agree. I added a function with some input validation - so it will at least return something for any inputs that do not lead to an error.

Answer (score 0):

I add a solution where edges can be selected with same probability than others, but they need to be mutually exclusive :

```
def rand2(k,n,edge=False):
    forbid=set()
    l=set()
    while len(l)<k:
        x=random.randint(1,n)
        if x not in forbid : 
            l.add(x)
            forbid.update({x,x-1,x+1})
            if edge and x in {1,n} : forbid.add(n+1-x)
    return l

from collections import Counter    

print(Counter([tuple(rand2(2,5)) for i in range(10000)])) 
#Counter({(2, 4):1943, (1, 4):1720, (3, 5):1711, (2, 5):1652, (1, 3):1637, (1, 5):1337})

print(Counter([tuple(rand2(2,5,edge=True)) for i in range(100000)]))
#Counter({(2, 5): 2060, (3, 5): 2026, (1, 4): 1981, (1, 3): 1975, (2, 4): 1958})
```